# Can I make a table like this picture using only one tag 'tr'?

Tags: html, tablesorter

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kA212.png]

I sort table to use libray "tablesorter js" but If I make it to use 2 or more 'tr' like the picture above, the library will not work.  so I only need to write 'tr'

Is it possible to make?

Comment: The real question is: Why can't you use two table rows?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `<td>` tag?

Comment: @Jomin its not possible without the use of another `<tr>`

Comment: Try DataTables to sort table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need two `tr` to create the table structure you desire.

The original tablesorter, includes a `cssChildRow` option which is set as `"expand-child"` by default. [It isn't documented](http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2011/06/jquery-tablesorter-missing-docs.html#cssChildRow), but you can [see a demo here](https://pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/tablesorter/tablesorter.htm). Here is [a
demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/1796/) of how it works, but as you can see you can not sort the second column.

HTML

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">Lamp</td>
</tr>
<tr class="expand-child">
  <td>Burn Time</td>
  <td>150 Hours</td>
</tr>
```

Script

```
$(function() {
  $('table').tablesorter({
    cssChildRow: "expand-child"
  });
});
```

In my [fork of tablesorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), you can still set the [`cssChildRow` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#csschildrow), but the default was changed to `"tablesorter-childRow"`. It automatically processes the extra column in the child row with no change necessary to the HTML or script - [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bbxxomhx/245/).

Comment: Thanks for your help.